# Congruences modulo a sum of two cubes

Tags: number-theory

$69660$ is congruent to $(7^3+1^3)$ $\pmod {(6^3+7^3) }$.

every integer N>0 $\equiv (a^3+b^3) \pmod {(c^3+d^3) }$, for some a, b, c, d? 
Exclude the trivial case a=b=c=d=1

Is there in Oeis a sequence of N of this type?

Comment: You can readily answer the second question yourself by searching OEIS for $69660$. There's only [one sequence that includes that number](https://oeis.org/A301806), and it seems unlikely that it's yours – the title is "Numbers $k$ such that the concatenation of $2^k-1$ and $2^{k-1}-1$ is prime".

Comment: @Peter can a Pari routine find all such numbers up to 10^3